# Matlab - Poorly conditioned polynomial

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, quadratic, cubic

I have a question asking me to  do linear, quadratic and cubic fit for population data, then estimate the population at the year 1915. The linear and quadratic fits work, however the cubic seems to raise an error telling me the polynomial is badly conditioned. The graph is quite close to the data values and seems to be a good fit. What can i do to remedy this? The code is:

```
clear;
clc;
close all;

year = [1815,1845,1875,1905,1935,1965];
population = [8.3,19.7,44.4,83.2,127.1,190.9];

rlinear = polyfit(year,population,1);
rquadratic = polyfit(year,population,2);
rcubic = polyfit(year,population,3);

newTime = linspace(1815,1965,100);
vrlinear = polyval(rlinear,newTime);
vrquadratic = polyval(rquadratic,newTime);
vrcubic = polyval(rcubic,newTime);

subplot(2,2,1)
plot(year,population,'ob',newTime,vrlinear)
xlabel('Year')
ylabel('Population (millions)')
title('Year vs. US population')

subplot(2,2,2)
plot(year,population,'ob',newTime,vrquadratic)
xlabel('Year')
ylabel('Population (millions)')
title('Year vs. US population')

subplot(2,2,3)
plot(year,population,'ob',newTime,vrcubic)
xlabel('Year')
ylabel('Population (millions)')
title('Year vs. US population')

estimate = polyval(rquadratic,1915);
fprintf('The estimated population in the year 1915 is %d million. \r',estimate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the warning message:

> Warning: Polynomial is badly conditioned. Add points with distinct X
>   values, reduce the degree of the polynomial, or try centering and
>   scaling as described in HELP POLYFIT.

centering and scaling solves the problem:

```
[rcubic2,~,mu] = polyfit(year,population,3);
vrcubic2 = polyval(rcubic2,newTime,[],mu);

subplot(2,2,3)
plot(year,population,'ob',newTime,vrcubic1)
hold on
plot(newTime,vrcubic2,'--r')
xlabel('Year')
ylabel('Population (millions)')
title('Year vs. US population')
```

[image]

The results show that in this case the two cubic fits are virtually the same.
See the [`polyfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html?refresh=true) help for further details on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of MATLAB, the warning also says you should [read the help](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html).
Particularly, you need to rescale your data to avoid numerical issues. Luckily, this is something that `polyfit` and `polyval` can do for you.

The reason why you need to do this, is that fitting a polynomial is quite ill-conditioned. Behind the scenes, it builds a matrix that contains your years raised to each power in the polynomial. So you have a matrix with entries like `1815` together with `1815^3 = 6e9`, that is not ideal for conditioning. The scaling ensures that you don't get large numbers in the matrix and hence the condition number improves.

Practically, you have to call `polyfit` and `polyval` a bit differently:

```
[p,s,m] = polyfit(year, population, order)
[populationAtOtherYears] = polyval(p, otherYears, s, m)
```

So your script would look something like:

```
clear;
clc;
close all;

year       = [1815,1845,1875,1905,1935,1965];
population = [8.3,19.7,44.4,83.2,127.1,190.9];

[linear.poly, linear.sigma, linear.mu] = polyfit(year,population,1);
[quadratic.poly, quadratic.sigma, quadratic.mu] = polyfit(year,population,2);
[cubic.poly, cubic.sigma, cubic.mu] = polyfit(year,population,3);

newTime = linspace(1815,1965,100);
% next line is to make a function for easier calling
evaluatePolynomial = @(fit, t) polyval(fit.poly, t, fit.sigma, fit.mu);
linear.evaluated    = evaluatePolynomial(linear, newTime);
quadratic.evaluated = evaluatePolynomial(quadratic, newTime);
cubic.evaluated     = evaluatePolynomial(cubic, newTime);

subplot(2,2,1)
plot(year,population,'ob',newTime,linear.evaluated)
xlabel('Year')
ylabel('Population (millions)')
title('Year vs. US population')

subplot(2,2,2)
plot(year,population,'ob',newTime,quadratic.evaluated)
xlabel('Year')
ylabel('Population (millions)')
title('Year vs. US population')

subplot(2,2,3)
plot(year,population,'ob',newTime,cubic.evaluated)
xlabel('Year')
ylabel('Population (millions)')
title('Year vs. US population')

estimate = evaluatePolynomial(quadratic,1915);
fprintf('The estimated population in the year 1915 is %d million. \r',estimate)
```